# Overriding the == operator in non-immutable types

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading, immutability, equality

The [MSDN Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator ==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx) state:

> By default, the operator == tests for
>   reference equality by determining if
>   two references indicate the same
>   object, so reference types do not need
>   to implement operator == in order to
>   gain this functionality. When a type
>   is immutable, meaning the data
>   contained in the instance cannot be
>   changed, overloading operator == to
>   compare value equality instead of
>   reference equality can be useful
>   because, as immutable objects, they
>   can be considered the same as long as
>   they have the same value. **Overriding
>   operator == in non-immutable types is
>   not recommended.**

Can anyone explain the reasoning behind the bold?

**EDIT** - Also, is this guideline relevant to the `==` operator only, or is it meant for the `Equals` method as well ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My educated guess would be to make things operate like the built in types in .NET do, namely that == should work like reference equality where possible, and that Equals should work like value equality where possible. Consider the actual difference between `==` and `Equals`:

```
object myObj = new Integer(4);
object myObj2 = new Integer(4);

//Note that == is only called if the ref'd objects are cast as a type
//overloading it.
myObj == myObj2; //False (???)
myObj.Equals(myObj2); //True (This call is virtual)

//Set the references equal to each other -- note that the operator==
//comparison now works.
myObj2 = myObj;
myObj == myObj2; //True
myObj.Equals(myObj2); //True
```

This behavior is of course inconsistent and confusing, particularly to new programmers -- but it demonstrates the difference between reference comparisons and value comparisons.

If you follow this MSDN guideline, you are following the guideline taken by important classes such as string. Basically -- if a comparison using `==` succeeds, the programmer knows that that comparison will always succeed, so long as the references involved don't get assigned to new objects. The programmer need never worry about the contents of the objects being different, because they never will be different:

```
//Mutable type
var mutable1 = new Mutable(1);
var mutable2 = mutable1;
mutable1 == mutable2; //true
mutable1.MutateToSomethingElse(56);
mutable1 == mutable2; //still true, even after modification
//This is consistent with the framework. (Because the references are the same,
//reference and value equality are the same.) Consider if == were overloaded,
//and there was a difference between reference and value equality:

var mutable1 = new Mutable(1);
var mutable2 = new Mutable(1);
mutable1 == mutable2; //true
mutable1.MutateToSomethingElse(56);
mutable1 == mutable2; //oops -- not true anymore
//This is inconsistent with, say, "string", because it cannot mutate.
```

It boils down to that there's no real technical reason for the guideline -- it's just to remain consistent with the rest of the classes in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a mutable type A and you create a set or objects of type A. Adding an object to the set should fail if this object already exists in the set.

Now let's say you add an object to the set, and then you change its properties so that it becomes equal to another object in the set. You've created an illegal state, where there are two objects in the set which are equal.

Comment: But using `Equals` instead of `==` doesn't fix this problem.

Comment: Another guideline is to always override `==` and `Equals()` together. And `getHashCoe()` too.

Comment: Actually it does - Equal is semantically different. Read the documentation for both to see the difference.

Comment: @TomTom: But `Set` uses `Equals`, not `==`, for the comparison, so the argument about the `Set` becoming inconsistent happens anyway.